# next-auth provide types for callback functions parameters

Tags: typescript, next.js, callback, next-auth

I'm using next-auth wit typescript and trying to define callback functions for jwt and session as below.

```
callbacks: {
async jwt({ token, account }) {
  if (account) {
    token.accessToken = account.access_token
  }
  return token
},
async session({ session, token, user }) {
  console.log('jwt callback')
  // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
  session.accessToken = token.accessToken
  return session
},
```

},
But typescript giving me type errors for paramters of functions. Is there a way to provide the types for them?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account }: {token: JWT, 
            account: Account}): Promise<JWT> {
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }: {session: Session, token: JWT, user: User}): Promise<Session>{
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            return session
    }
```

You also need to augment some of the types. You can copy the code below. Place it in types/next-auth.d.ts.

```
import NextAuth, { Account, DefaultSession, User } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface Session {
        accessToken?: Account.accessToken
    }
}


declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
    interface JWT {
        accessToken?: Account.accessToken
    }
}
```

Explanation:
Basically, we just need to use the types that are already present in the next-auth (Session, JWT, Account).
However, these types only contain necessary properties. Hence, we need to augment its type.