# NextAuth Type error: Type 'JWT' is missing the following properties from type 'User'

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am new to nextauth credentials provider, and I have been following different tutorials on youtube and searching for answers here. I'm getting a Type Error in NextAuth while building a production build but my local is running fine. The error is coming from the session callback of the next-auth.

If I delete the node_modules and reinstall, I start getting the error on my development.

Here is my `[...nextauth].ts`

```js
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import { fetchUserDetails, getAccessTokenApi } from '@/api';
import redis from '@/lib/redis';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'jsmith' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
        const { username, password } = credentials as any;
        const { sessionId } = req.query as any;

        // ...some logic

        const user = // ...some API call

        if (user) {
          return { ...user, id: user.merchant_id };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token;  // <== THIS LINE GENERATING THE ERROR

      return session;
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: `/dashboard/login`,
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

`src/types/next-auth.d.ts`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { User } from '.';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: User;
  }
}
```

`src/types/index.ts`

```js
export interface User {
  username: string;
  user_type: string;
  merchant_id: string;
  authenticated: boolean;
  locked: boolean;
  active: string;
  last_login: number;
}
```

`package.json`

```json
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
```

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You're missing the JWT type in the session, see here for how someone else fixed it => https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498139/3530423